# I have silver badges but "Amazing Grace" is not awarded

Tags: support, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

I have 2 silver badges at Stack Overflow, I got them months ago I think. When I try to get an **Amazing Grace** hat from Winter Bash, it says *You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet.* So what's going wrong, is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I own 2 silver badges at Stack Overflow, I got them months ago I think.

Exactly that. You need to earn the badge *during Winter Bash* for it to count towards the hat. Otherwise it would be a little too easy. You got your badges on [August 14th](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious?userid=11420760) and [May 26th](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast?userid=11420760), so they don't count.

Answer (score 7):

All hats on Winter Bash are for what you did in the specific time range of Winter Bash, if it was for what you completed in your whole time in SE, a person who got hats one year will always get those same hat triggers on other years, that's the point of Winter Bash, to see how many hats you can get in the specific time range, otherwise it wouldn't be fun.

As you said:

> I own 2 silver badges at Stack Overflow, I got them months ago I think.

You have to get the silver badges during Winter Bash, that's the point, the times you got the badge was not during Winter Bash